# Traversing a custom linked list

Tags: java, traversal, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a program to simulate memory fragmentation. The input file tells what segments need to be input at what time.

A sample file is:

```
N  
C 200  
P 1 2 3  
P 2 3 4  
P 2 3 1  
R  
E
```

where `C` is the memory size, `P` is the segment in the order (size, start time, and life time), and `R` (should) print out a report showing what segments, and any holes are in memory and where.

One of the rules of this assignment is to create a linked list of the events, where insertions and deletions of the segments are created as events,  and I need to traverse the event list. 
UPDATE: I have something different, but I know for sure it's not inserting my Events into the Event List.  I don't understand why.  Does anyone see where my logic is off?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class TestEventList{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    //read file
    File file = new File("b.txt");

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            //send it to interpret file method:
            interpretFile(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }  //end try-catch
}

public static void interpretFile(String command) {
    EventList evtList = new EventList();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(command);


    char initialCommand = command.charAt(0);

    if (initialCommand == 'N') {
        System.out.println("Name");
    } else {
    }//end else
    //file error

    char commandCode = command.charAt(0);
    String skip = sc.next();  //skips next character to get to integers
    switch (commandCode) {
    case 'C':/*create Memory! which means, create Event!
                Form: Event(int startTime, Segment memSegment)*/
        int size = sc.nextInt();

        Segment defaultMemoryNode = new Segment(size, 100, false );
        /*create event node*/
        Event insertDefaultNode = new Event(0, defaultMemoryNode);
        /*insert this event*/
        evtList.insertEvent(insertDefaultNode);

        break;

    case 'P':

            int segmentSize = sc.nextInt();
            int segmentStart = sc.nextInt();
            int segmentLife = sc.nextInt();

            int segmentExpiration = segmentLife + segmentStart;

            Segment memorySegment = new Segment(segmentSize, segmentExpiration, true );
            Event addSegment = new Event(segmentStart, memorySegment);
            evtList.insertEvent(addSegment);

            memorySegment.occupied = false;

            Event removeSegment = new Event(segmentExpiration, memorySegment);
            evtList.insertEvent(removeSegment);

            break;

    case 'R':
        evtList.traverseEventList();

        break;
    case 'E':
        System.exit(0);
        }//end switch

}//end interpretfile method
}  //end class T.E.L.

/*This class has-a Linked List, has-a memoryNode, has-a Segment*/
class MemoryList{

 private Node memoryNode = new Node();
 private Segment memorySegment = new Segment();
 private LinkedList memoryList = new LinkedList();
 Node head;
 Node current;

public MemoryList(){
   super();
}
   /*define blocks and holes*/
   public void insertBlock(Segment memorySegment) {
    current = head;
    if (current == null) {
        memoryList.Add(memorySegment);
        System.out.println(memorySegment.size);
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("Checking for room");
        System.out.println(current.getSize());
        int invalidFit=0;
        if(current.getStatus() == false && current.getSize()>=memorySegment.size){
            System.out.println("Verified space");
            int freeSpace = current.getSize() - memorySegment.size;
            memoryList.Add(memorySegment);
            createHole(freeSpace);
            current = current.next;
         }  //end if
         else {
            current = current.next;

        } //end else
    }//end else
  }  //end insert block

  public void removeBlock(Segment expiredSegment){
    current = head;
    //search for segment

    while(current.next != null){
        if(current.getTimetoLeave() == expiredSegment.timeToLeave
                && current.getSize() == expiredSegment.size){

        memoryList.Remove(expiredSegment);
        int freespace = expiredSegment.size;
        createHole(freespace);
    }
        else{
            current = current.next;
        }
    }//end while
}

    private void createHole(int space) {
    Node hole = new Node(space, 100, false);
    memoryList.Add(hole);
    //test if there are two holes together. if so, mergeHoles.
    }

   *Merge 2 Consecutive Holes*/
   private void mergeHoles(Node a, Node b) {
   //getPrev(a);  //find previous of node a
   //use the size through the end of a's prev to
   //get start of prev.next (a)+

   //make a point to b.next?
  } //end mergeHoles

  public void traverseMemoryList(){
    current = head;

    if(current == null){
        System.out.println("Memoryless");
    }
    else{
        while(current.next != null){
            if(memoryNode.getStatus() == false){
                System.out.println("Hole");
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Segment of size " + current.getSize());
        current = current.next;
    }
   }

} //end MemoryList

class MemoryNode extends Node{
   public MemoryNode(){
    super();
   }


}
class Segment{
  int size;
  int timeToLeave;
  boolean occupied;

  /*constructor*/
  public Segment(){

  }

public Segment(int newSize, int newTime, boolean isOccupied){
    this.size = newSize;
    this.timeToLeave = newTime;
    this.occupied = isOccupied;
 }

}

class Node {
     private int size;
     private int timeToDepart;
     boolean occupied;  // True if segment, false if hole
     Node next;
     public Object data;  //data in a node

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(int segmentSize, int timeToLeave, boolean type) {
    this.size = segmentSize;
    this.timeToDepart = timeToLeave;
    this.occupied = type;

    }

    public int getSize() {
    return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int segmentSize) {
        size = segmentSize;
    }

    public int getTimetoLeave() {
        return timeToDepart;
    }

     public void setTimetoLeave(int timeToLeave) {
            timeToDepart = timeToLeave;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean type) {
        occupied = type;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return occupied;
    }

}  //end Node

/* class LL has-a Node*/
class LinkedList{
  private Node listNode= new Node();

   Node current;
   Node head;
   Node prev;

   int size;

/*Constructors:*/
public LinkedList() {
    super();
}

public LinkedList(int j, int k, boolean l) {
    super();  //essentially the same as a node
}

/*LL proprietary methods*/
 /*test if the list is empty, to avoid NullPointerException*/
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
}
//insert method:

public void Add(Object data1) {
    listNode.data = data1;

    /*special case: list is empty*/
    if (isEmpty()) {
        listNode.next = head;
        head = listNode;
        head.data = listNode.data;
    }

    else{
        current = head;

        while(current.next != null)
    {
        current.data = data1;
        current.next = null;
        head = current;
    }
        current.data = data1;
        current.next = head; //newNode now points to head
        head = current;      //now newNode is the head
    }
}

public void Remove(Object delData) {
    /*pointers*/

    //special case: if head is the removed node;
    if (current.data == delData) {
        head = current.next;
    } else {
        prev = head;  //it's not the head, keep moving.
        current = current.next;

        while (current.next != null) {  //reached end of list
            if (current.data == delData) {      //if
                prev.next = current.next;       //just skip the current node
            } else {
                prev = current;          //now prev is that node
                current = current.next;  //current is the next node

            }
        }  //end while
        //what if current.next = null (it's at the end)?
        if (current.next == null && current.data == delData) {
            prev.next = null;

        }
    }//end else
}
public void traverse(){
    if(head== null){
        System.out.println("no elements to show");
    }
else{
    current = head;
    while(current.next != null){
        current = current.next;
    }

  }}
  }// end LL class

 /*class EventList has-an Event, is-a LinkedList*/
class EventList{
   private Event event = new Event();
   private LinkedList evtList = new LinkedList();
   private MemoryList memList = new MemoryList();
   Node current;
   Node head;
   int time;  //set to the most recent time

   /*constructor*/
   public EventList(){
    super();

  }

  public void actionOfEvent(Event event1){
    Segment p = event.getMemorySegment();
    if(p.occupied == true){
        insertSegment(event1);
    }
    else
        removeSegment(event1);
   }

  //a linked list to control creation of events
  public void insertEvent(Event event) {
    current = head;
    if(current == null){

        evtList.Add(event);
        System.out.println("Added 1st event " + event.startTime);
    }
    else{
        while(current.next != null){
            if(event.startTime <= event.getTime()){
                //if the event start was before the current time...
                evtList.Add(event);
                current = current.next;
            }
            else{
                current = current.next;
            }

        }//end while
        evtList.Add(event);
        System.out.println("Added 2nd event");
    }
   }//end insertEvent

  public void traverseEventList(){
    current = head;

    if(current == null){
        System.out.println("At time " + event.getTime());
        System.out.println("uneventful");
       }
    else{
        while (current.next != null){
        Segment segment1 = event.getMemorySegment();
        if(segment1.occupied = true){
            memList.insertBlock(segment1);
            System.out.println(segment1.size + " inserted");
        }

        else{
            memList.removeBlock(segment1);
            System.out.println(segment1.size + " removed from memory.");
        }


        }
      }
   }

  public void insertSegment(Event addEvent){
    addEvent.getMemorySegment();
    memList.insertBlock(addEvent.getMemorySegment());
    }
  public void removeSegment(Event expEvent){

}

} //end eventList

 /*class Event is-a Node*/
class Event{

   int startTime;
   Segment memoryNode;
   int time;

   public Event(){
       super();
   }

   //pretty much the same as Node.
   public Event(int newStartTime, Segment newMemNode){
      super();
      this.startTime = newStartTime;
      this.memoryNode = newMemNode;
   }

   public void setTime(int newStartTime){
      time = newStartTime;
   }

   public int getTime(){
    return time;
   }

   public void setMemorySegment(Segment newMemNode){
       memoryNode = newMemNode;
   }

   public Segment getMemorySegment(){
       return memoryNode;
   }

}//end class Event

class Report{
   int currentTime= 0;


    //this creates and prints the segments/holes in the list at curTime

}
```

Comment: Upvote for the homework tag. Let me look over this and I'll see what I can do about an answer for you.

Comment: I would really encourage you to try and clarify your classes, you have a lot of ambiguity and overlap between some of them.

The names are rather confusing in places; try to stick with a naming convention that makes it easy to know what object is doing what and is responsible for.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and it seems that you never call:

```
setMemoryNode();
```

This is causing NullPointerExceptions.

Also:

Some of the multiple event instances are being caused by these lines:

```
EventSequenceList expiredNode = new EventSequenceList(newMemNode,
1, expir, 1, true);
insertEvent(expiredNode);
```

I will edit this as I see more.

Comment: I'm taking a last look at the code, but I'm going to need to get some sleep soon.
Keep us updated on your progress.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few (other) remarks

**Design**

You use a lot of inheritance. Is that really necessary? Later on, for production code, you should consider using *composition* instead of *inheritance* and code against interfaces. That will remove a lot of ugly dependencies and improve maintainability. Now you have

> EventSequenceList **is-a** MemoryList **is-a** LinkedList **is-a** Node

Just from the names, I have some doubt, that a LinkedList really **is-a** Node. I expect a  *Node* in trees or graphs and even there it's usually a **has-a** relationship.

**Naming**

Sometimes you break with Java naming conventions: method names should not start with a capital letter (like `Add`). Sometimes you use one-letter-variable names (like in most of your constructors).

Sometimes a methodname does not tell us, what the method is really doing (like `iterpretFile` which actually does not interpret a file but only a single command that *may* have been read from a file)

---

The more I look at the assignment, the more I get the feeling, that you'll get stuck with your design sooner or later (more sooner than later). From what I read, what is required:

- One event model class. A Class, that represents an insertion or deletion event.
- One memory model class. A Class, that represents the entire memory
- One segment model class. A Class that represents a segment. A memory class **has** a list or an array of segments
- One linked list that holds all events. This custom linked list may be capable of inserting an event *at the right place*
- One reporting class. A class that can create and print a report.
- One input file parser. It will use the input to

  - create a memory class (with an appropriate number of segments)
  - create insertion and deletion events from the `P` lines
  - insert the events in the linked list

Absolutely *no* inheritance is needed.

---

Edit - in response to your last comments

A *memory* has-an array of cells. The cells are indexed, starting with 0. They are not linked, so I actually don't see any reason to use a `LinkedList` here. A memory model could look like:

```
public class Memory {
  private int[] cells;
  public Memory(int size) { cells = new int[size]; }
  public void store(int index, int value) { 
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) throw new IllegalArgumentException("..");
    cells[index] = value;
  }
  public int read(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) throw new IllegalArgumentException("..");
    return cells[index];
  }
}
```

A *segment* could be seen as a subclass of Memory. In real life, a segment is requested from a memory manager and the manager allocates a region, if possible. Segments are totally independant, no link between them, no use for a LinkedList here. A quick draft:

```
public class MemoryManager {
  private Memory managedMemory;
  public MemoryManager(Memory memory) { this.memory = memory; }
  public Segment getSegment(int size) {
    int startAddress = allocateSegment(int size);
    if (startAddress != -1) {
      return new Segment(this, startAddress, size);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Segment extends Memory {
  private MemoryManager memoryManager;
  private int startAddress;  // usually - a handle, so that the memoryManager can
                             // relocate the segment - we keep it simple
  public Segment(MemoryManager memoryManager, int startAdress, int size) {
    super(size);
    this.memoryManager = memoryManager;
    this.startAddress = startAddress;
  }
```

Now back to the events.

*One of the rules of this assignment is to create a linked list of the events* [`eventList = new EventList<Event>()`] *, where insertions and deletions of the segments are created as events* [`new Event(EventType.INSERT, int time, Segment segment)); new Event(EventType.DELETE, int time, Segment segment);`] *, and I need to traverse the event list* [`for(Event event:eventList)`].

That's the task. implement an `Event` class, implement an `EventList` class, implement a small enum `EventType`. The challenge is to implement an `insert` method in `EventClass` that inserts two events for one `P` line at the right places (timestamps).

Comment: Great suggestions, but I don't see that this answers the question. I feel this would be more qualified as a (series of?) comment(s).

Comment: @Zéychin - fixing his actual problems will not help with his homework (to my opinion). It will help understanding what went wrong (you're analysis is valuable!!). So in addition to your answer, I decided to provide additional support ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D I am in no way making negative comments about what you are doing; I absolutely appreciate what you're doing! In fact, I feel that more people should provide quality suggestions such as yours.
I am more questioning whether your post should be considered an 'answer', as per the StackOverflow model.

Comment: @Zéychin (in this case: yes, because there was no question in the post ;-) Bre just mentioned that he/she is *unsure*)

Comment: @Andreas_D  Hi. I started from scratch, but I'm a little confused as to how I should set this up. To me the design seems as follows: Memory is-a LinkedList, has-a Segment.  A Segment is-a Node. The event list is-a Linked List, has-a(n) Event. The Event is-a Node.

Comment: @Bre - come back with new questions, if you're stuck and need more help :) (and search on SO doesn't help ;) )

Comment: I did update my code, doing my best to use a better design. I am still having trouble, though. I know my events aren't actually being inserted into the event list, because it always outputs "Uneventful" when I call traverseEvents() in interpretFile. If someone could help me see where what I'm doing wrong, I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Brick wall! Would the solution be a lot more complicated if the memory were also a linked list?

Comment: *what* do you want to achieve with a LinkedList? A memory is a linked list of *what* ?

Comment: A memory list is a linked list of segments and holes.

Comment: I know what you want - but the *list of segments* should be owned by the memory manager - and you don't have to add holes to that list. A memory is not such a list. You should always try to model the *real world*, that makes things much, much easier, as well for coding, as well for understanding the code later on. Modeling is like painting a picture: try to draw photo realistic.

Comment: It's another component of the assignment. :( I had to look at the assignment again. It's okay, though, I think the Event List is my biggest drawback.  It is good to know real life isn't so bad.